# Checking if a value is assigned to a boolean variable in specs

Tags: scala, specs

In specs bdd framework(http://code.google.com/p/specs), i can check if a value is assigned to a string or not using :

```
SomeClass.strVal == null mustBe false
```

Now, suppose the class has a boolean value boolVal. How to check if a value true or false was assigned to boolVal or not ?

Please Help
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acccording to [this page](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.2/scala/Boolean.html), the Boolean class derives from AnyVal. Therefore boolean is a value type and no boolean variable can be `null`. In fact, since Scala runs atop the java pplatform, it probably has the default value of `false`

In general, it is not good practice to leave variable uninitialized. When a variable is declared, give it a value. This alleviates the need to do these kinds of checks.

Comment: Are you sure that default value for `Boolean` is `true`? I always thought that it's `false`.

Comment: sorry, I meant false but typed true. I need coffee it seems.